# Polar decomposition has unitary operator implies kernel of adjoint is trivial.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, orthogonality

Let $T\in B(H)$ for $H$ a Hilbert space.

Let $T = U|T|$ be the polar decomposition of a bounded operator $T$. I was able to prove that $U$ is unitary implies $\operatorname{ker}T = \{0\}$. However, $\operatorname{ker}T^*$ should also be trivial, but I am not sure how to get there. I have tried using the identity $$\operatorname{ker}(T^*) = \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp$$ or the fact that $\operatorname{Im}(T^*)$ lies dense in $H$. But to no avail.

Comment: $$T^* = |T|U^*.$$

Comment: Why should $|T|^* = |T|$?

Comment: Because $|T|$ is self-adjoint. Often $|T|$ is realized as $\sqrt{T^*T}$. The self-adjointness should follow pretty quickly from the proof.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of self-adjoint. I can find that $(|T|^2)^*=|T|^2$. But this does not imply that |T| is self-adjoint, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see that $|T|^2$ is self-adjoint, so it has a square root which is self-adjoint. Now $|T|^2$ is also a positive operator, since $$<T^*Tx,x> = <Tx,Tx> = ||Tx||^2\geq0$$ for all $x\in H$. Which implies that the square root is unique, hence $|T|$ is self-adjoint. So we find that $T^* = |T|U^*$.

Take $x\in \operatorname{ker}T^*$. We know that $\operatorname{ker}T = \operatorname{ker}|T| = \{0\}$. Since $|T|U^*x = 0$, $x\in\operatorname{ker}U^*$. But since $U$ is unitary we get $$0 = <U^*x,U^*x> = <x,x> = ||x||^2$$ So $x= 0$.